# Microsoft Point of Service for .Net Core

Tags: c#, pos, pos.net

Is there any update or version of Pos.Net 1.14 for .Net Core?
I have tested the sdk and apparently it is not compatible with .net Core.

I would appreciate if someone could suggest me alternatives or work around to make it work for .net core. Currently the sdk only works if I set the target framework to .NET Framework 4.0 +.

For your information, I am developing an app utilizing EPSON Thermal Receipt Printer.

Comment: If I read correctly POS.NET is no longer actively supported. Instead check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-printer

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon that cannot be! EPSON OPOS SDK for .NET depends on that and the recent update was last year. Any suggestion on the alternative?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon that is UWP though, not .NET or .NET core :(

Comment: How can we get official word of MS on this ? I am having hard time understanding how we should move on with .NET Core since there is no replacement apis.

Comment: @NullReference lemme know if you ever hear any updates on this. Looks like theyre pushing commercial apps to Windows Store in my opinion, hence the UWP.

Comment: I guess you can use OPOS (ActiveX version of UnifiedPOS) from .Net Core. There was a plan for UnifiedPOS v2.0 but not sure what is its status. https://www.omg.org/retail/unified-pos.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, there is no sign that such things are being developed.

If you want to do something on .NET Core, you will have to send/receive device control commands directly from the application via a serial port or network connection, or use library that supports it.

Comment: I ended up write the code for printing using Windows library itself. Kinda disappointed on this matter as .NET Core is expected to succeed .NET Framework in the future. Even Microsoft recommend creating new apps in Core.

Comment: I found a project like this some time ago. [lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET) Something may be helpful.